# How to take only ONE image from a <<Collection>> of Images which is nested inside a <<Model>>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Given following is the "Property" Model class where it consists of the Collection of PropertyImages as an attribute :-

```
public class Property
  {
    public virtual ICollection<PropertyImage> PropertyImages { get; set; }
  }
```

Now,This is the "PropertyImage" Model which can have multiple number of images for any particular "Property" :-

```
public class PropertyImage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public Property Property { get; set; }
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }

    }
```

Given below is the View/Carousel where I am Trying to display only ONE image of One Particular Property.When Carousel slides to next,only One Image of another Particular Property should display. :-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                @for (int i = 0; i <ViewBag.FeaturedProperties.Count; i++)
                {
                    var item = ViewBag.FeaturedProperties[i];
                    var itemClass = i == 0 ? "item active" : "item";
                    <div class="@itemClass" overflow:hidden">

                    //This is the problem

                        <img src="~/Image/@item.PropertyImages.FileName" class="img-responsive" style="height:400px;width:1140px;" />

                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div class="transbox pull-right">
                                <p>@item.PropertyDescription</p>
                                <p>Location: @item.City,@item.Country</p>
                                <p>Property Cost: @item.PropertyCost</p>
                                <p>Minimum Investment Amount: @item.MinimumInvestmentAmount</p>
                                <p>Remaining Investment Amount: @item.RemainingInvestmentAmount</p>
                            </div>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" value="View Property" id="carouselLink"
                                   onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("PropertyDetails", "Home", new { id = @item.Id })'" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The carousel was fine when PROPERTY had only one image stored in it.But now that there are multiple images,I dont know how to select only one particular image to be displayed in the Carousel.

The Viewbag.FeaturedProperties carries the necessary data.

Any Help would be appreciated.Thank You!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8sev.jpg)

Comment: The just pass one image to your view (use a view model with a property for the single image you want). And what does `ViewBag` have do do with this - you have not shown any code relating to setting a `ViewBag` property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks. :)